# Will Ruby extensions built in OS X work on Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, macos, unix, ruby-c-extension

I want to make a Ruby extension for a C (with C++ libraries) program that will run on a CentOS server, but it would be more convenient for me to work on a Mac (especially without having to reinstall all the 3rd party libraries).

Since they're both UNIX-based, would creating the library in OS X throw it off once I put it on CentOS, or should I just man up, install CentOS, and do it all there?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't it be built in either? A mac binary isn't going to run on a linux box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even have 100% source compatibility between them, although you can easily stick to what will work on both.

There is no binary compatibility between Linux and OS X; even the basic object file formats differ (Linux uses ELF, OS X uses Mach-O).

Comment: So would you recommend I just bite the bullet, install CentOS, and make it there?

Comment: What would your other option be, given that making it on OS X won't work?

Comment: Yeah, good point.  May as well better be safe than sorry anyway. Thanks!